# Unmap <leader> hotkeys in VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to use longer leader hotkeys to group or associate several common things that I do.

For instance `<leader>dnd` would do something, and `<leader>dnt` would do something related but different.

However, if `<leader>d` or `<leader>dn` is aready taken by a plugin, a longer leader hotkey is impossible.

Is there a way to unmap leader commands from plugins?

Answer (score 3):

You can always `:unmap` any mapping after a plugin file has been sourced. This would typically be done in `~/after/plugin/fixmapping.vim` for global mappings. But this is clumsy, and nothing more than a workaround.

If the plugins are (dare I say, correctly (1)) written with leaving the final choice to the end-user in mind, they would permit to bind any hot-key sequence of your choice to `<Plug>(something)` -- and then they would detect there is already something bound to `<Plug>(something)` and they would not associate `<leader>whatever` to `<plug>(something)`.

You'll have to dig into the documentation of the plugin with a default configuration you don't like to see first if it permits to override defaults, and then how it can be done. If the plugin doesn't permit it, I'd recommend you open a *request for enhancement/change*.

(1) Sometimes we just publish a quickly written solution/proof of concept. The first drafts are not ideally designed/written. Yet they can evolve to be more *professional*. Do not be afraid to contact plugin maintainers.